# Avoiding opamp saturation - working with apd

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, saturation

i have [avalanche photo diode](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/ad1500-10-500883%5B2%5D.pdf) with which i am trying to digitalize the current from TIA through a comparator, the diode biased using a [HVDCDC](http://www.emcohighvoltage.com/datasheets/caseries.pdf)

the source is being a 20ns laser with a PRF of 3Khz

the circuit is as below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSpwrA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

the output of opamp for an high intensity light is like above, we can see the opamp fully saturated, but i am clue less about the over shoot and ringing effect, this happened when i have put my bias voltage 300V, i am not able to stop the opamp to enter in to saturation.

even if i see the datasheet of DC-DC CA05N, it can maximum source 2mA of current, and the peak current of didoe is only 0.25mA, so i understood the dcdc current is exceeding 2mA

so to avoid the opamp going in to saturation i tried to use a 300K in series with the source but still the opamp went to saturation,

it evident that in order to make the opamp not to go in to saturation, the only way i can try is to reduce the bias voltage to as less as possible, so i operated it at 70V for which the response is as below.

[image]

reasons are unknow for the expansion of 20ns pulse to 100ns even through the APD is having a BW of 70MHz,

so in order to operate the APD properly, i understood i have to bias with higher voltage to see proper response for low light, but at the same time i have to avoid saturation.

i feel limiting the current to the TIA will solve problem, kindly suggest some ways to bypass the excess current which is to the opamp.

Kindly throw some light on behaviour of APD in saturation also

**EDIT:**

as the answers suggested to go for a unity gain stable equivalent, i went for changing my opamp to LTC6269 which is 400Mhz unity gain stable

below is the result i got with photo diode polarity inversed, so you may see a inverted output, but effect persists

[image]

the analog support was suggesting me also on using a subber at the photo diode bias so i used a 20ohm in series with 100p cap thinking this disturbance is due to the power supply i am using, frankly i am clueless how to tweak a snubber

please help me in identifying the problems rootcause

**EDIT2:**i have to tweak my Cf accordingly i feel, to avoid this, i dont think this is ringing, i feel i have solved my problem , will comeback with results shortly

**EDIT3** : replacing Cf with 4pF given me a clean pulse with out any ringing
Thanks for the help

**EDIT4**: But after few experiments i identified that i am not saturating the photodiode/opamp completely, so i have increase the pulse width and pulse power on photo diode with which my response turned like below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The amplification and reaction speed of an APD depend on the current through it. It's a bad habit of the physics community to use APDs with a voltage source and a series resistor for biasing. As you have witnessed, this fails in high dynamic range applications. I suggest you change your biasing circuit to provide a constant current instead of constant voltage.

The ringing you see is from your opamp. You are using a variant that is not unity gain stable. The -10 in the part number denotes that it's a decompensated opamp for a gain of at least 10 (Linear's opamp numbering convention). But for this kind of circuit to work, you need unity gain stability.

I suggest you have a look at Linear Appnote 92 which discusses a few circuits for APDs.

Comment: i understood that i should have constant current source in place, but also limited to current less than my saturation current of opamp.can you please given how to provide such constant current source based biasing for my application. i am unable to find such app notes for voltages high like 300V, also how can i modify my exiting ckt to keep opamp stable, i feel i have to keep my gain as low as 10

Comment: any how to keep it stable i am maintaining cin / cf ratio to 10

Comment: i have repeated the experiment using a stable opamp to see the effect but the phenomenon persists, kindly help

Comment: I guess it's time to open up a new question and show us the new circuit.

Comment: i mistook the parasitic ringing, i have put a valid 4pF cap in feed back because which the stable opamp did not pose any problems, but its still a unsolved question how to exploit the full bandwidth of the decompensated opamps, recently LT rolled out a 10GHz GBWP opamp, what are they for if they are not useful?

Comment: You are aware, that the GBP does not equate to achieved bandwidth? The LTC6409 has a -3dB bandwidth of just 2GHz and a differential slew-rate of 3300V/us. Depending on your circuit one of these numbers will limit you and give you an effective usable bandwidth anywhere between 50MHz and 300-500MHz. And that assumes that you have an ideal PCB, with no stray capacitance. While we have amazing components today, physics is still a bitch and doesn't let you do whatever you want.

Comment: agreed, but at same bandwidth with a LTC6409 i can achieve much higher gain isn't it ? LT engineer was suggesting me to use a T in feedback to make it stable, https://ez.analog.com/thread/99459-working-with-avalanche-photo-diode-beginner-problems

Comment: added a edit, i have made the opamp to stay in saturation for more than 40ns now the response is quite different, with 10ns i was getting a bit less overshoot, this time the overshoot has gone very bad